# Bash: shell script if statement using multiple conditions including regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, if-statement, sh

I am currently studying the shell script and having some syntax issue.

what I am tyring is to make the 'if' statement to catch any user-input with alphabet, except the "giveup" line

here is the code that I built:

```
if [ $usrGuess =~ *[:alpha:]* && $usrGuess != "giveup" ]
```

once I run the code, it gives out the error message saying that:

```
[: missing `]'
```

If you guys have any solution to this, I will be happy to hear your advice :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` (`[`) builtin of any shell (or the external one) does not support putting conditional construct e.g. `&&`, `||` or multiple command separator e.g. `;` inside it.

Also, `[` does not support Regex matching with `=~`. BTW your Regex pattern is not correct, it seems more like a glob pattern (and that should suffice in this case).

Both of the above are supported by the `[[` keyword of `bash` and not all shells support these.

So, you can do:

```
if [[ $usrGuess = *[[:alpha:]]* && $usrGuess != "giveup" ]]
```

Here, I have moved for `[[` and used the Glob match `$usrGuess = *[:alpha:]*` (dropped Regex matching).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I am totally new to this field and you provided a great explanation for what I was wondering about. Again, Thanks alot!

Comment: @HojinLee Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use double brackets, as your condition is composite:

```
if [[ $usrGuess =~ *[:alpha:]* && $usrGuess != "giveup" ]]
```

Comment: wow, thank you for your quick answer! It is quite embarrassing, but I still don't get how it works. What I have found is that the double bracket makes the process faster, but I don't understand what is the difference between those two in terms of syntax. Do you mind explaining this for me?

Comment: `*[:alpha:]*` is not a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using `grep` command would also work.

```
if grep -v '^giveup$' <<<$userGuess | grep -iq '^[a-z]*$'
```

In this example, we use exit code of grep command to make a if-else decision. Also note the '-q' option to second grep command. This ensures that the grep command matches the pattern silently.

Pros: Less complicated if() clause.

Con: There are two `grep` processes executed.

Comment: Thanks, I have never thought about this approach. Literally I started to look at this shell script yesterday and it does not feel anywhere near the Java. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to retain POSIX compatibility, use the `expr` command to perform the regular expression match.

```
if expr "$usrGuess" : '[[:alpha:]]*' > /dev/null && [ "$usrGuess" != "giveup" ]
```

Either way, I'd opt to check against "giveup" first; if that check fails, you avoid the more expensive regular-expression check altogether.